# Can not load Rails. Getting error to run bundle install, but that wont work either

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle-install

Whenever I run `rails s` I get:

> Could not find multi_json-1.11.0 in any of the sources
>   Try running `bundle install`.

Running `bundle install` in turn gives me:

```
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
Updating git://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store.git
fatal: Refusing to fetch into current branch refs/heads/master of non-bare repository
Retrying git fetch --force --quiet --tags 'git://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store.git' "refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*" due to error (2/3): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git fetch --force --quiet --tags 'git://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store.git' "refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*"` in directory /usr/local/rvm/gems/cache/bundler/git/activerecord-session_store-cf0cfe22b7614cc4fcd416e139ff2bd62ebd6f1d has failed.
If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/cache/bundler/git/activerecord-session_store-cf0cfe22b7614cc4fcd416e139ff2bd62ebd6f1d'
fatal: Refusing to fetch into current branch refs/heads/master of non-bare repository
Retrying git fetch --force --quiet --tags 'git://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store.git' "refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*" due to error (3/3): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git fetch --force --quiet --tags 'git://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store.git' "refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*"` in directory /usr/local/rvm/gems/cache/bundler/git/activerecord-session_store-cf0cfe22b7614cc4fcd416e139ff2bd62ebd6f1d has failed.
If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/cache/bundler/git/activerecord-session_store-cf0cfe22b7614cc4fcd416e139ff2bd62ebd6f1d'
fatal: Refusing to fetch into current branch refs/heads/master of non-bare repository
Git error: command `git fetch --force --quiet --tags
'git://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store.git'
"refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*"` in directory
/usr/local/rvm/gems/cache/bundler/git/activerecord-session_store-cf0cfe22b7614cc4fcd416e139ff2bd62ebd6f1d
has failed.
If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory
'/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/cache/bundler/git/activerecord-session_store-cf0cfe22b7614cc4fcd416e139ff2bd62ebd6f1d'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: > If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory
`'/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/cache/bundler/git/activerecord-session_store-cf0cfe22b7614cc4fcd416e139ff2bd62ebd6f1d'`.

Comment: Can you show your Gemfile?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the additional information in your comments I think this is probably a spring caching issue, try stopping spring with: spring stop and then retry running your app